# ArcGISProject object not working with path reference

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, import, feature-class

I am currently working on a Python script for ArcGIS Pro and can't seem to get it to add data from path when I reference the project with the full path.

```
import arcpy
test = r'H:\main\python_code\test.gdb\test'
p = r'C:\Users\Daniel\Documents\ArcGIS\Projects\MyProjects\MyProject.aprx'
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject(p)
m = aprx.listMaps('Map')[0]
m.addDataFromPath(test)          # Nothing happens here but code loads and completes
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")
m = aprx.listMaps('Map')[0]
m.addDataFromPath(test)          # loads, completes and shows the feature as a new layer
aprx.filePath
'C:\\Users\\Daniel\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Projects\\MyProjects\\MyProject.aprx'
```

So when I use "CURRENT" it adds feature class to the map. When using the specific filepath it seems to load but doesn't add anything to the map.

I get no errors.

Answer (score 1):

I think when you call a project by path (instead of "CURRENT"), it is working 'behind the scenes' and you need to use

> aprx.save()

before you will see any changes.  Try adding that to your code and re-opening the project.

Comment: I tried this both with external pyhon code as well as inside arcGIS Pro and the feature class did not appear on the Map. There might be something different holding it back in my case. Thanks for the reply none the less.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to create the feature layer first, then add it to the map.

```
test_lyr = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(test,"test").getOutput(0)
map_lyr = m.addLayer(test_lyr)[0]
```

Comment: At first I thought this finally worked but somehow my GIS will not even add a layer while I reference the project with full path. I'm finding this really weird that it will not show the actual layers i'm creating.